# Old logo on the hot questions list at stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design

While browsing the hot questions list, I encountered an old (?) logo of Security.SE:

http://stackexchange.com/questions?page=2

[image: Screenshot of the hot questions list showing the old logo]

The current [favcion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) of Security.SE:
[image: Screenshot of the current favcion]

(I prevented caching issues by deleting the cache, using 3 different browsers and by accessing the site via my mobile phone. All methods led to the same favicon.)

All other sites seem to be represented by their current favicon. Why does Security.SE have two different logos?

Comment: I don't understand the question. I see our site logo as expected. Can you clarify?

Comment: @RoryAlsop If you go to http://security.stackexchange.com, you see a different favicon than shown in the hot questions list and in the StackExchange Android app. All other sites seem to be consistently identified by the same logo.

Comment: Com - you maybe have a caching issue. I see the same icon in your picture as at the top of this page. The one in your picture is the current icon.

Comment: @RoryAlsop Please see my update.

Comment: Ahh - I see what you mean now. The simple answer is that there is no bug, and no outdated icon. These are both correct :-)

Comment: @RoryAlsop Alright, thanks for the answer. Shall I delete this question?

Comment: If you want to you can - it doesn't really matter much. Up and down votes on meta aren't important, and it may be someone else will wonder the same thing.